# Как автоматически открывать панель переменных при старте отладки в VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, отладка

Я переместил окно *Variables* в панель вниз вместо левого сайдбара. Теперь, когда я запускаю отладку, она сначала открывает панель *Terminal*. Как сделать так, чтобы автоматически открывалась *Variables*?

Использую CodeLLDB и CMake Tools, если это важно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]